# Using both @AutoMatter and @AutoValue in a same project

Tags: code-generation, auto-value

Recently I ran into the situation that I  had to use both @AutoMatter and @AutoValue to generate code in a project. However this did not work as code was not generated for one of the class annotated (@Automatter). If this is a compiler plugin, why didn't it work?

Comment: Can you confirm that you used the right case when specifying the annotation? re: @Auto**M**atter and not @Auto**m**atter. I'm assuming it wouldn't compile if you were using the wrong case, but it's worth it to check :) Also ensure that you have the `auto-matter` dependency listed in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file

Comment: @ThaDon Yes I did use the right case

Comment: Does this mean it's working with other classes annotated with `@AutoMatter`?